# How to execute git bundle command on some branch on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

My issue is what to write to execute git bundle command after cloning some branch, then copy the output file to remote machine :

```
 stage('Cloning project') {
        git branch: 'release_branch', url: 'repo_url'
    }
    
    stage('create bundle') {
        git bundle  ..........
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all git commands are available as native workflow steps. As an alternate, I myself have successfully used shell scripts precisely for this purpose in which all non supported command are wrapped in a shell script. These scripts are part of the git repository itself (usually in build directory, can be anything you wish though).

For your use-case, you can use similar approach and wrap "git bundle ..." along with file transfer (using sftp, curl, aws cli or what ever works in your environment) in a single shell script. Say this file is checked in at path build/bundle_transfer.sh then you can invoke this script using following syntax within your pipeline.

```
    stage('Cloning project') {
        git branch: 'release_branch', url: 'repo_url'
    }
    
    stage('create bundle') {
        sh 'build/bundle_transfer.sh'
    }
```

Make sure your script is checked in with executable attributes set otherwise it'll fail execution in jenkins environment. Should you wish to use any write operation on remote repository (not needed for "git bundle ...") then you'll likely end up using [Credentials Binding](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/) in your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it works fine with me..
stage('create bundle') {
     sh 'bash ./bundle_script.sh'
    }